# Cypress Hangs with cy.clock()

Tags: javascript, cypress

Currently I have a set of tests that I am running with `cy.clock()` set to a time in the future. This line of code is resting in the `before()` code block so that all of the tests are using this future date with a `restore()` in the `after()` block.

The problem that I am facing is that the test runner is being sluggish, and at times frozen, unresponsive. Tests will not go all the way through (without error), and when tests do finish the test runner UI is frozen.

Is there any suggestions? Removing the `cy.clock()` code does make the test runner go normally, but without it the tests are fragile and may not succeed unless tests are run at a certain time of day.

```
describe("A group of tests", () => {
    before(() => {
        cy.clock(Date.UTC(2037, 0, 3, 12, 0, 0, 0), ['Date']);
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
      cy.viewport(1000, 1000);
    });

    // Tests here
    
    after(() => {
        cy.clock().then((clock) => {
            clock.restore();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What are your tests exactly? There is pretty much nothing to go on here.

Comment: I didn't find adding the actual tests bring any benefit for this question as its pretty generic.

Answer (score 4):

If you are sure that `cy.clock()` is causing the problem, you can substitute [@sinonjs/fake-timers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sinonjs/fake-timers).

Internally, Cypress clock uses the same library. Using it directly gives you more options to fine-tune the code.

For example `advanceTimeDelta` option allows you to control the automatic ticks of the clock. Make it lower if you have flaky tests.

```js
const FakeTimers = require("@sinonjs/fake-timers")

cy.window().then((win) => {
  const clock = FakeTimers.withGlobal(win).install({
    now: Date.UTC(2037, 0, 3, 12, 0, 0, 0),
    toFake: ["Date"],
    shouldAdvanceTime: true,
    advanceTimeDelta: 100,
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you for this. If you are using things like lodash `debounce` just overriding the Date with cy.clock will likely break your page because `debounce` internally is repeatedly calling `Date.now` to check how much time has passed. It's a shame that `cy.clock` doesn't allow you to simulate time passage natively when you override the date.

Comment: Yes, luckily `cy.clock()` is just a wrapper around SinonJs and you can enhance of bypass as you wish.